# I have 10 elements that are the same, how can I click on the third one?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm having trouble getting my test to pass when trying to select an image that appears a number of times on a page, and I'm trying to select the 3rd or 4th image. I can easily test  selecting the first image.

Link: [click this link](https://www.fundingcircle.com/lend/loan-requests/) (Then try clicking 3rd image in table)

Environment: Mac OSX 10.7.5, Firefox 19.0.2, Ruby 1.9.3p194, watir-webdriver 0.6.2

Here is the code that I have tried to use and the error I have received:

```
@browser.image(:alt, 'Avatar')[2].click 
Error:  undefined method `[]' for # Watir::Image:0x007f829b89e8b8> (NoMethodError)

@browser.image(:alt, 'Avatar', :index => 3).click
Error:  expected Hash or (:how, 'what'), got [:alt, "Avatar", {:index=>3}] (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Doh!!!!! I just found my mistake and corrected it. It's now working. code that works is:   @browser.images(:alt, 'Avatar')[2].click

Comment: Apologies for posting, something so trivial

Comment: Your second example also has a typo - `@browser.image(:alt => 'Avatar', :index => 3).click` should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone, here is the answer (Thanks to Justin for spotting the typo in the second example):

1st example:

```
@browser.images(:alt, 'Avatar')[2].click
```

2nd example:

```
@browser.image(:alt => 'Avatar', index => 3).click
```